# How can I access a string defined in a .java file in the corresponding .xml file?

Tags: android, string, textview

in myapp.java, I define a string based off user input from another activity.  How can I access that string in activity_myapp.xml and show it in a TextView?  I've tried android:text=myapp.stringname, but it doesn't seem to work.

Edit:   The problem is not that I'm unable to get the text into the .java file, but I'm unable to get it into the corresponding .xml file.

Comment: XML files are pre-compiled by the build tools and cannot be modified at run time as you would like to do. Runtime modifications must be made from java, in this case using setText(

Comment: That answers it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you can do this in java. as you have got the value from previous activity just put it in the current activity TextView.

```
TextView example = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourtextview);
example.setText("yourstring");
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I suggest you do is put that text as an extra in the intent. In the other activity find the text view by id that you want to populate the data with. Then set the text based on that Extra into from the Intent.

```
String val = editText.getText();
Intent i = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
i.putExtra("some_string",val);
startActivity(i);
```

And in the other Activity, onResume you can do the following

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("some_string");
}

newEditText.setText(value);
```

Hope this helps.